# How to avoid multiple "using" declarations at non-dependent names in a template class derived from another template class (c++)?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, inheritance

I'm creating an Ordered Linked List derived from a Linked List base class, where both are templated. I know because of the Two-Phase name lookup I've got specify that the variables depend on something, like "this->head", "LinkedList::head" or specify "using LinkedList::head" at the beginning. I prefer using the third one, but when there are a lot of members that are going to be inherited, it becomes very verbose. Is there some way to avoid this?

```cpp
// Here I have the Base Class

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
...
public:
    ...
    template <typename TArg> void push_front(TArg&& v0);
    template <typename TArg> void push_back(TArg&& v0);

    void pop_front();
    void pop_back();
    void erase(const LinkedList<T>::Iterator& pos);
    void clear();
    ...
protected:
    Node<T>* head;
    Node<T>* last;
    size_t _size;

    LinkedList<T>::Iterator _begin;
    LinkedList<T>::Iterator _end;
};
```

And the derived class

```cpp
// Here I have the derived class

template <typename T>
class OrderedList : public LinkedList<T>
{
    using LinkedList<T>::head;
    using LinkedList<T>::last;
    using LinkedList<T>::_size;
    
    using LinkedList<T>::_begin;
    using LinkedList<T>::_end;

    using LinkedList<T>::push_back;
    using LinkedList<T>::push_front;
    using LinkedList<T>::clear;
    ...
    ...

public:
    ...
};
```

What can I do to deal with that?

Comment: Perhaps not directly relevant, but (1) deriving ordered  whatever from whatever may not be the best odea and (2) an ordered linked list may not be the best idea either.

Comment: I derived from Linked List because the only functionality that gets changed is the insertion, so that allows me to reuse functionality and specialize some cases.

Comment: I know that I may have used something like a functor or predicate (I asked this 3 years ago, now I'm more experienced) but it would be interesting to know if nowadays there is some workaround for this necessary evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a necessary evil. If we could have done what this question asks, then we would have lost the ability(not sure if its good) to name members in derived class as the same name in base class.

See how this example works.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A {
 public:
    int member;
    virtual void Set(int value) {
        member = value;
    }
};

class B : public A {
 public:
    int member;
    void Set(int value) override {
        member = value;
    }
    void Show() {
        std::cout << "member: " << member << " A::member: " << A::member << "\n";
    }

};

int main()
{
  B b;
  b.Set(5);
  b.Show();
}
```